# How to pull Google Calendar events for the coming week?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I am working on a script that pulls Google Calendar events to a Google Sheet for organization and processing. I want to get all events for the upcoming week, but I can only get it to give me today or a specific date. Example:

```
var today = new Date("January 2, 2018 00:00:00 PST");

var events = cal.getEventsForDay(today);
```

Thanks

Comment: Look at the documentation for Calendar/getEvents(startTime,endTime).

Answer (score 0):

I think what yo need is a way to calculate the dates for the upcoming week.  Shold be something like this.

```
var nextMonday = new Date();
nextMonday.setDate(nextMonday.getDate() + (1 + 7 - nextMonday.getDay()) % 7);
var endDate = new Date();
endDate.setDate(nextMonday.getDate() + 7);
```

You can then use the dates with getEvents

```
cal.getEvents(nextMonday, endDate);
```